# Selectively modify file names

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, batch-rename

I have a folder containing a large number (over 1500) ttf files many, not all, of which have somehow been incorrectly named.  e.g. `arialttf` instead of `arial.ttf`.  Is there a shell command I could use to change the defective file names so the tailing ttf part is converted to .ttf?

I am reasonably competent with bash commands but this I am afraid is beyond my capabilities. I'd much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter the following command in the directory with the misnamed files:

```
for f in *[^.]ttf; do mv "$f" "${f%???}.ttf"; done
```

You may wish first to put an `echo` before the `mv` to make sure that the command is doing what you expect.

The command works by setting each `f` to each file name ending in `ttf`  *not* preceded by `.`, then renaming the file to the name with the last three characters removed (ie `ttf`) with `.ttf` then appended.

Comment: Much more elegant than my solution.  Well done!

Comment: @tbenz9 - Your answer is quite similar: sorry I crossed with it. If I'd seen your answer first I would have added mine as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I completed this with a small bash script.  Save that in the directory with all your ttf files and execute it.  It finds all files that don't contain ".ttf" and renames them to include the extension.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *ttf ;
do
  if [[ $f != *'.ttf' ]]
  then
        mv $f ${f::-3}.ttf
  fi
done
```

Comment: although I have accepted AFHs answer I am voting up yours because it is easier to understand,  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that you have `rename` `Perl` script it's very simple:

```
$ touch arialttf
$ touch somethingttf
$ touch thirdttf
$ ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja ja 0 Oct 27 18:30 arialttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja ja 0 Oct 27 18:31 somethingttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja ja 0 Oct 27 18:31 thirdttf
$ rename 's,ttf$,.ttf,' *
$ ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja ja 0 Oct 27 18:30 arial.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja ja 0 Oct 27 18:31 something.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja ja 0 Oct 27 18:31 third.ttf
```